# python - undefined variable?

Tags: python, debugging, variables, error-reporting

Does python have some undefined variable / debug mode which will output a notice/warning?

PHP allows you to modify the error_reporting to turn on notice warnings which mean doing

```
<?php
echo $foo;
```

will throw an "Undefined variable foo on line 2.......

does python have something similar?

I had a bug where I was doing

```
db.connect
```

instead of

```
db.connect()
```

and I was hoping python would throw a 
undefined variable connect...

can you bump up the error reporting level or similar in python?

Comment: Fortunately for us, it does throw an exception. In what circumstances did you not get the error? In Python, you can always create new attribute (db.connect = 1, for instance), this might have tricked you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python complains about undefined variables, without any adjustments to its [warning system](http://docs.python.org/library/warnings.html):

```
h[1] >>> print x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

In your case `db.connect` actually **has a value**, namely a function object. So your connection isn't undefined.

```
h[1] >>> def hello(): pass
     ... 
h[1] >>> x = hello
h[1] >>> print x
<function hello at 0x100461c80>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not an undefined variable. You refer to the existing method `connect` - if there wasn't one, you'd get a `NameError` as The MYYN shows - but you don't call it. That's perfectly valid as far as the language is concerned - in fact, this behaviour (when part of a bigger expression) is sometimes extremely useful. But let alone, it's pointless of course. I suppose static analysis tools such as [pylint](http://www.logilab.org/project/pylint) or [PyChecker](http://pychecker.sourceforge.net) might complain about this (I'm not sure though, I rarely make this kind of mistake) and using them won't hurt anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no such option in Python. However, there are tools like [PyChecker](http://pychecker.sourceforge.net/), which will help you finds bugs which in other languages are caught by a compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool like pylint http://www.logilab.org/project/pylint

Example

```
class A(object):
    def fun():
        return None

a = A()
a.fun
```

Pylint snippet warning:

```
R:  2:A.fun: Method could be a function
```